# Sqlfluff rule L025 breaks due to postgres `generate_series()`

Tags: postgresql, sqlfluff

I'm using [sqlfluff](https://www.sqlfluff.com/) to lint my postges code. I'm down to a single linting error, in my test code, that I dont know how to fix by adjusting my sql nor how to configure it.

The rules im breaking is [L025](https://docs.sqlfluff.com/en/stable/rules.html#sqlfluff.core.rules.Rule_L025).
The issue is that sqlfluff thinks, i'm not using the alias `i` because I dont write womething like `i.value`.

With the following code:

```sql
insert into private.account (
  account_first_name,
  account_last_name,
  account_display_name,
  account_email,
  account_password
)
select
  'Random' as account_first_name,
  'User' as account_last_name,
  concat('Random User ', i) as account_display_name,
  concat('random', i, '@email.com') as account_email,
  gen_random_hash() as account_password
from generate_series(1, 200) as i;
```

and the coresponding error:

```
== [test\generate_accounts.sql] FAIL
 L: 38 | P: 33 | L025 | Alias 'i' is never used in SELECT statement.
 All Finished!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do agree with the linter here. `i` is a table alias and shouldn't be used as a column reference. It's cleaner to use

```
from generate_series(1, 200) as g(i)
```

or whatever naming you prefer.

Then reference the value as `g.i`